# i need to fire a function in gwt right after module is being loaded

Tags: java, gwt, timer, scheduling

i need to fire a function right after module is being loaded , as in right after onModuleLoad() execute 
what should i use to implement this thing , Timer or scheduleDeferred or anything else ?

```
something like
 
Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {

            @Override
            public void execute() {
                Window.alert("bon jour! amis.");

            }
        });
     
or 
...
...

timer.schedule(2000);

or
??
```

Comment: What do you mean by "right after module is being loaded"? Is it when the view is fully initialized and rendered ? Is it after all async services launched on load are over ? 
For now I would say : use the scheduler, not the timer.

Comment: yes exactly , right after the view is fully initialized and rendered .. but scheduler is making loaded view and html unresponsive , while its loading other contents(Widgets)

Comment: According to the documentation, a deferred command is executed after the browser event loop returns. Unless widgets also use ScheduledCommand or load content asynchronously, your ScheduledCommand  is not responsible of the unresponsiveness.

Comment: alright , thanks man , let me get back to you later. thanks again

Comment: @wingdings: Thanks to your question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Finding out when a GWT module has loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210451/finding-out-when-a-gwt-module-has-loaded) might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Scheduler.scheduleEntry](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/core/client/Scheduler.html#scheduleDeferred%28com.google.gwt.core.client.Scheduler.ScheduledCommand%29) in your EntryPoint implementation.  I do this now to inject additional (non-GWT handled) stylesheets, and I need to ensure this happens after the view renders.

Comment: u mean like

`Scheduler.get().scheduleEntry(new ScheduledCommand() {...});`

it says in jdoc
An "entry" command will be executed before GWT-generated code is invoked by the browser's event loop. This type of command is appropriate for code that needs to know when "something happens." 
whats browser event loop

Comment: problem with that is , its only loading when i hit the refresh button , as in its only executing commands when i hit the refresh button.

Comment: When you refresh, it'll re-load your EntryPoint, so onLoadModule() is invoked again.  At the end of your onLoadModule(), invoke `Scheduler.get().scheduleEntry(new ScheduledCommand() {...});`.